# how to show dropdown list based on selection of a particular item in other drowdown list in jquery?

Tags: jquery, mysql, jsp, jquery-ajaxq

I have created 2 Tables in mysql , india_states and india_cities.
I have inserted values from mysql itself where india_states has 4 states , and in india_cities there are 16 city names , means one state Maharashtra in india_states table has 4 cities in india_cities table.
I have successfully shown the states in a dropdown using  in my html page using jquery , below is the code for the states.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var states_name="";
$.ajax({
     type: 'GET', 
        url: 'http://localhost:8082/JqueryForm/html/jsp/states_name.jsp', 
        data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 
        var select = $('#select_states').empty();
              $.each(data, function(i) {
                  states_name = data[i].state_name;
                  console.log("states_name:" + states_name);
                  select.append('<option value="'
                          + states_name
                          + '">'
                          + states_name
                          + '</option>')
                 });
             }
      });
});
```

Now what i want to do is , when i select maharashtra , the other dropdown should automatically show 4 cities related to maharashtra only , for that i have put the states_id in india_cities table.
I have also created a jsp page which is used to show my cities in json view based on the following url

http://localhost:8082/JqueryForm/html/jsp/city_names.jsp?states_id=1

```
{
1: {
city_name: "Mumbai"
},
2: {
city_name: "Pune"
},
3: {
city_name: "Thane"
},
4: {
city_name: "Navi Mumbai"
}
}
```

and here is my jquery code for the above

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=
    ([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null){
       return null;
    }
    else{
       return results[1] || 0;
    }
}
var states_id = $.urlParam('states_id');
var cities_name="";
$.ajax({
     type: 'GET', 
        url: 'http://localhost:8082/JqueryForm/html/jsp/city_names.jsp', 
        data: { states_id: states_id }, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 
        var select = $('#select_cities').empty();
              $.each(data, function(i) {
                  cities_name = data[i].city_name;
                  console.log("cities_name:" + cities_name);
                  select.append('<option value="'
                         + cities_name
                         + '">'
                         + cities_name
                         + '</option>')
            });
         }
     });
});
```

india_states.jsp

```
<%
JSONObject finalJSON = new JSONObject();
Sql_Server details = new Sql_Server();
request.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");
response.setContentType("application/json");
List<String> list = details.getIndiaStates();
int recordCounter = 1;
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject formDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
    formDetailsJson.put("state_name", list.get(i));
    finalJSON.put(recordCounter, formDetailsJson);
    ++recordCounter;
}
out.println(finalJSON.toString());
```

%>

In place of `states_id` when i put "1" it shows me the values of maharashtra state, but how to get the states_id dynamically ?
So need some help to populate my other dropdown based on the values of first dropdown.
Thank you

Comment: You need to call the ajax function on changing the state dropdown. I mean you need to create method consists of ajax which should be called on change first dropdown values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you that from your JSON, where you are collecting the value of states like :

```
states_name = data[i].state_name; // get this value from your JSP like 123#Maharashtra
```

so that in your success function you can split this value using:

var abc=(data[i].state_name).split("#");

and put id of the state in the value attribute of option tag.

So, in the end you have the IDs associated with each state in your option value.

Change in your code like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var states_name="";
$.ajax({
     type: 'GET', 
        url: 'http://localhost:8082/JqueryForm/html/jsp/states_name.jsp', 
        data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 
        var select = $('#select_states').empty();
              $.each(data, function(i) {
                  states_name = data[i].state_name;
                  var abc = states_name.split("#");
                  console.log("states_name:" + states_name);
                  select.append('<option value="'
                          + abc[0]
                          + '">'
                          + abc[1]
                          + '</option>')

              });

        }
});
```

and then on the change event of your states drop down call your ajax like :

```
$('#select_states').on("change", function () {
var state_id=$('#select_states').val();
$.ajax({
         type: 'GET', 
            url: 'http://localhost:8082/JqueryForm/html/jsp/cities_name.jsp', 
            data: { id : state_id }, 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) { 
                  //populate the cities drop down.

            }
    });

});
```

Comment: sir i have updated my code , i have put my jsp code which shows my state names , can u tell me how to do like u said , 123#Maharashtra?

Comment: You can refer my answer for format the string like as you want `111#MH`. Rest was already given by @Brijesh

Comment: @Brijesh sir , abc[1] is giving undefined , so it should be abc[0] for both and thank you for your reply

Comment: @brijesh sir , i have found out the solution myself , dont need to split and all ,  got the value of states_id from states_id = data[i].states_id; and passed it inside <option value="states_id"> and did this , $('#select_states').on("change", function () {
var state_id=$('#select_states').val();

Comment: @narahari_arjun ok ..thats good ..The solution was if you want both the values ..

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt ok sir, but thanx alot for replying , if it wasnt your answer , it wouldnt had clicked me to do it other way

Comment: @narahari_arjun your wc.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have issue in java side. To create a json array in jsp use the following code snippet,

```
JSONArray cellarray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject cellobj = null; //new JSONObject();
int state_id=request.getParameter("state_id");

try{
    // Do not open DB connection like this, this is for your understanding
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");  
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from city where state_id='"+state_id+"'  ");
    while(rs.next()){
        cellobj = new JSONObject();
        //concatinate id with string
        cellobj.put("citi_name", rs.getString(1) +"#"+ rs.getString(3));
        cellarray.add(cellobj);
    }  
    System.out.println(cellarray);
}
catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e);
}
```

Here get data from db and add it into json array. this jsp page wii return json array to `(111#Tamilnadu) - expected format` to your ajax. You can iterate afterwards.